# How do I ensure that only one route gets called with ExpressJS `.route()`

Tags: node.js, express, routes

If I was writing this in a front end in React router, I would use a  statement to make sure that ***only one route*** was being called. However, this is for the backend, which is written in plan Node.js.

My aim is to get `/forms` to return all forms, and `/forms/:requestor` return just those forms for a particular requestor, i.e.

```
localhost/forms -> getFormsRoute()

localhost/forms/:requestor -> getFormsForRequestorRoute()
```

I have a router hooked up to a `/forms` url from the main `App.js` file:

```js
// essential parts of App.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const {FormRouter} = require('./routers/FormRouter');

const app = express();
app.use('/forms', FormRouter);
```

A simplified version of the code in `FormRouter.js` (using arrays and not db queries) is as follows:

```js
// essential parts of FormRouter.js
const express = require('express');
const {forms} = require('../scaffolding/forms'); // some dummy data in an array ...

const FormRouter = express.Router();

const getFormsForRequestorRoute = (req, res, next) => {
  const { requestor } = req.params;
  console.log(`getFormsForRequestorRoute for ${requestor}`);
  const formsForRequestor = form.filter(function (form) {
    return form.requestor === requestor;
  });
  console.log(formsForRequestor);
  res.json({ rows: formsForRequestor });
};

const getFormsRoute = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('getFormsRoute');
  res.json({ rows: forms });
};

FormRouter.route('/:requestor')
  .get(getFormsForRequestorRoute);

FormRouter.route('/')
  .get(getFormsRoute);

exports.FormRouter = FormRouter;
```

When I ping `/users/smith`, the console tells me that I'm hitting `getFormsRoute` on it's own.

Clearly, this is not what I was expecting. What's confusing me is that it's not hitting `getFormsForRequestorRoute` and then `getFormsRoute`!

Where is my understanding lacking? How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your routes as follows which is pretty much a standard:

```
FormRouter.route('/forms/:requestor')
  .get(getFormsForRequestorRoute);

FormRouter.route('/forms')
  .get(getFormsRoute);
```

**UPDATE** after further questions from OP

This is how I register routes.

app.js

```
require('./routes/users')(app); // app is express instance
```

users.js

```
module.exports = (app) => {
   ....

   app.route('/users')
      .get(getUsers)
      .post(createUser);

   app.route(”/users/:id")
      .get(getUser);

}
```

Comment: So I shouldn't be setting up the `app.use('/forms', FormRouter);` in the `App.js` parent?

Comment: I normally handle routing in the routers only, see the update

Comment: Thanks Chev. I'll try it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call next() otherwise express would match the first path you have declared which is **:/requestor**. If you send the response back the req/res cycle is ended and the second route is not called. Keep calling next if you want to match multiple routes. Do it like this

```
const express = require('express');
    const {forms} = require('../scaffolding/forms'); // some dummy data 

const FormRouter = express.Router();

const getFormsForRequestorRoute = (req, res, next) => {
  const { requestor } = req.params.requestor;
  console.log(`getFormsForRequestorRoute for ${requestor}`);
  const formsForRequestor = form.filter(function (form) {
    return form.requestor === requestor;
  });
  console.log(formsForRequestor);
  res.json({ rows: formsForRequestor });
};

const getFormsRoute = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('getFormsRoute');
  res.json({ rows: forms }); 
};

FormRouter.get('/:requestor',getFormsForRequestorRoute);




FormRouter.get('/', getFormsRoute);

exports.FormRouter = FormRouter;
```

Comment: Err, not exactly what I was hoping for; my aim as stated at the top is to get `/forms` to return **all** forms, and `/forms/:requestor` return just those forms for a **particular requestor**. The change you outlined returns nothing! ;-)

Comment: My bad i wanted to give you an example but i missed the some code. So '/' is a different pattern than '/:requestor' and calling next wouldn't match anything so not getting a response is right. But if you have another path that like the one i just added '/:id' calling next would cause it to hit the second route as well.

Comment: Which means the behavior you stated in your question is correct. /forms wouldn't hit both the functions. It would just hit one which is getFormsRoute.

Comment: :-) OK, but that still doesn't quite answer my question

Comment: Honestly I am confused your questions says that 'how do I make sure that I only hit one route'. The example you give exactly does that which means your question is your answer. So I was trying to answer why doesn't it hit both. And there are two reasons, 1) it's not recursive matching, just like / and /forms are not same, neither are / and /:requestor. 2) even if multiple route do match you need to call next() explicitly before sending response.

Comment: No, that’s not my question, sorry. I want to write code that allows me to hit two different routes. If I supply `/:requestor` I want that to show me just the forms that match that ID. If I supply `/`, then I want that to show me all the forms.

Comment: If it's still not clear, you can take a look at the following link. It has a few examples https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html.